# specify Ip of the Client in Client/Server manually (By hand)

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I am building a Client/Server using TCP socket in C#

here is the code for the server :

```
namespace Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Socket> _clientSockets;
        private Socket server = null;
        private byte[] _buffer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 13000));
            server.Listen(10);
            server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
        }
        private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket client = server.EndAccept(AR);
            _clientSockets.Add(client);
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnRecieve), client);
        }
        private void OnRecieve(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket client = (Socket) AR.AsyncState;
            Int32 numberOfBytes = client.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] rec = new byte[numberOfBytes];
            Array.Copy(_buffer, rec, numberOfBytes);
            MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rec));
            client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnRecieve), client);
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
            _buffer = new byte[4096];
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the Client Code:

```
namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Socket _client;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 port = 13000;
            IPAddress my_Ip_Address = IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(my_Ip_Address, port);
            _client.BeginConnect(endPoint, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), null);
        }
        private void OnConnect(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            _client.EndConnect(AR);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte [] toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
            _client.BeginSend(toSend, 0, toSend.Length ,SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), _client);
        }
        private void OnSend(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket client = (Socket) AR.AsyncState;
            client.EndSend(AR);
        }
    }
}
```

but when click button on the client, it's not connecting to the server ..
it's only connected to the server if I changed this statements on the client side

```
 IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(my_Ip_Address,  port);
```

TO

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
```

then it's connected and the message Box in the server appear whit text "Connected" , why ??
because I want to specify the IP address of the client by hand not by using  `IPAddress.Loopback`

Comment: What is the value you're giving `textBox1`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan value like 192.168.2.33

Comment: Is it _like_ that address? Or is it actually that address? Are you sure that the address you're passing as `my_Ip_Address` is in fact the IP address of the computer?